# How to add or define new value on button element which already have innerText?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I trying to build Tip calculator which have 5%, 10%, 15%, custom buttons. I can selected all buttons with forEach and changed the background and text but how to add value to the buttons which have already innerText (5%,10%,15%..). My goal is to add / define somehow value to the button  like "button 5 %" = 0.05, "button 10" = 0.1 etc;
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYcRI.png)

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Space+Mono:regular,italic,700,700italic);

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

:root {
  /*
     - Very dark cyan: hsl(183, 100%, 15%)
- Dark grayish cyan: hsl(186, 14%, 43%)
- Dark grayish cyan: hsl(184, 14%, 56%)
- Light grayish cyan: hsl(185, 41%, 84%)
- Light grayish cyan: hsl(189, 41%, 97%)
- White: hsl(0, 0%, 100%)
     */
  --primary: #26c0ab;
  /*Neutral*/
  --very-dark-cyan: hsl(183, 100%, 15%);
  --dark-grayish-cyan: hsl(186, 14%, 43%);
  --dark-grayish-nians-cyan: hsl(186, 14%, 56%);
  --light-grayish-cyan: hsl(186, 14%, 84%);
  --light-grayish-nians-cyan: hsl(186, 14%, 97%);
  --white: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
}

body {
  font-family: "Space Mono", sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.5;
  background-color: var(--dark-grayish-nians-cyan);

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

h1 {
  padding-bottom: 85px;
}

input {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: var(--very-dark-cyan);
  height: 46px;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: var(--light-grayish-nians-cyan);
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  text-align: right;
}
.icon-dollar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 62px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 15px;
}

.container {
  padding: 2rem;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: white;
}
.bill_info h3 {
  padding-bottom: 13px;
}

.btn {
  padding: 0.8rem 1.5rem;
  border: none;
  background-color: var(--very-dark-cyan);
  color: white;
  font-family: "Space Mono", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  border-radius: 5px;
  max-width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.custom {
  background-color: var(--light-grayish-nians-cyan);
  color: var(--dark-grayish-nians-cyan);
  font-weight: bold;
}
.bill {
  padding-bottom: 36px;
  position: relative;
}

.bill h3 {
  padding-bottom: 21px;
}
.select_tip {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  grid-template-rows: 47px 47px;
  gap: 13px;
}
.select_tip h3 {
  padding-bottom: 22px;
}
.people {
  padding-top: 32px;
  position: relative;
}

.icon-person {
  position: absolute;
  top: 87px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 15px;
}

.bill_result {
  margin-top: 32px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: var(--very-dark-cyan);
  padding-top: 2.75rem;
  padding-left: 1.5rem;
  padding-bottom: 1.5rem;
  padding-right: 24px;
}

.tip_amount {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding-bottom: 24px;
}
.amount {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  color: white;
}

.amount small {
  color: var(--dark-grayish-nians-cyan);
}
.tip_amount_header_person,
.tip_amount_header_total {
  color: var(--primary);
  font-size: 23px;
}
.total_reset {
  padding: 0.8rem 1.4rem;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: var(--primary);
  color: var(--very-dark-cyan);
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

@media (min-width: 700px) {
  .container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    max-width: 850px;
  }
  .bill_info {
    padding-right: 50px;
  }
  .select_tip {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    gap: 15px;
  }
  .tip_amount {
    padding-bottom: 46px;
  }
  .tip_amount_header {
    font-size: 35px;
  }
  .bill_result {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  .bill-result > button.total_reset {
    margin-bottom: 92px;
  }
  .reset_button {
    padding-top: 4rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> <!-- displays site properly based on user's device -->

  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./images/favicon-32x32.png">
  
  <title>Frontend Mentor | Tip calculator app</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Spli<br>tter</h1>
 <section class="container">
    <div class="bill_info">
      <div class="bill">
        <h3>Bil</h3>
        <input type="text"  class="bill_input">
        <img src="images/icon-dollar.svg" alt="dollar" class="icon-dollar">
      </div>
      <h3>Select Tip %</h3>
      <div class="select_tip">
        
        <button type="text" class="btn five" data-number>5%</button>
        <button type="text" class="btn ten"data-number>10%</button>
        <button type="text" class="btn fifteen"data-number >15%</button>
        <button type="text" class="btn twentyFive"data-number >25%</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn fifty"data-number >50%</button>
        <button type="text" class="btn custom" data-custom>Custom</button>  
      </div>
      <div class="people">
        <h3>Number of People</h3>
        <input type="text"  class="people_input">
        <img src="images/icon-person.svg" alt="dollar" class="icon-person">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="bill_result">
      <div class="tip_amount">
        <div class="amount">
        <label for="">Tip Amount</label>
        <small> / person</small>
        </div>
        <h3 class="tip_amount_header_person"></h3>
      </div>
      <div class="tip_amount">
        <div class="amount">
        <label for="">Total</label>
        <small> / person</small>
        </div>
        <h3 class="tip_amount_header_total"></h3>      
      </div>
      <div class="reset_button"><button class="btn total_reset">Reset</button></div>
      
    </div>

 </section>

 
 <script src="app.js"></script> 
</html>
```

```
enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to convert the % of a button to a decimal:

```
parseInt((insert class name).innerHTML.substring(0,((insert class name).innerHTML).length - 1)) / 100.0
```

For example:

```
parseInt((btn-five).innerHTML.substring(0,((btn-five).innerHTML).length - 1)) / 100.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`data-attributes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) for the percentage and amount, calculate the amount from its value and add the result to `span[data-tip]` within `div#amount`. Here's a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The element (`button, div#amount`) texts are completely done via css (`:after/:before`) and manipulation of the data-attributes

```js
document.addEventListener(`click`, evt => {
  if (evt.target.dataset.percentage) {
    const amount = +document.querySelector(`[data-amount]`).dataset.amount;
    const percent = +evt.target.dataset.percentage;
    document.querySelector(`[data-tip]`).dataset.tip =
      ` (tip: ${percent}% = $${(0.01 * percent * amount).toFixed(2)})`;
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  font: normal 12px/15px verdana, arial;
  margin: 2rem;
}

[data-amount]:before {
  content: '$'attr(data-amount);
}

[data-percentage]:after {
  content: attr(data-percentage)'%';
}

[data-tip]:after {
  content: attr(data-tip);
}
```

```html
<div id="amount" data-amount="30.00"> <span data-tip=""></span></div>
<p>
  <button data-percentage="5"></button>
  <button data-percentage="10"></button>
  <button data-percentage="15"></button>
</p>
```

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain well. I would like to convert buttons to decimal, so  when I click button 5% to get  as result 0.05 . At the same time I want to keep button with innerText of 5 %

Answer (score 0):

I think I found solution:

```js
 // grab all eelements

const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.btn')

const billInput = document.querySelector('.bill_input')
const resetButton = document.querySelector('.total_reset')
const customButton = document.querySelector('.custom')
const peopleInput = document.querySelector('.people_input')
const tipAmountPerson = document.querySelector('.tip_amount_header_person')
const tipAmountTotal = document.querySelector('.tip_amount_header_total')



buttons.forEach(function(item) {
    item.addEventListener('click', addTip)
})

function addTip(e) {
  buttons.forEach(btn => {
    if(e.target.innerHTML == btn.innerHTML) {
  tipValue = parseFloat(btn.innerHTML) / 100
  console.log(tipValue)
  } 
  })
 
   
}
```

```html
 <div class="select_tip">
        
        <button type="text" class="btn">5%</button>
        <button type="text" class="btn">10%</button>
        <button type="text" class="btn">15%</button>
        <button type="text" class="btn">25%</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn">50%</button>
        <button type="text" class="btn custom" data-custom>Custom</button>  
      </div>
```